How to implement AppTrackingTransparency for tvOS using Unity
My Apple TV app has been rejected because: "Your app's binary contains references to App Tracking Transparency, but you have indicated you do not intend to ask users for permission to track at this time."
My question is, how do I implement App Tracking Transparency into tvOS? The Unity App Tracking Transparency framework work for tvOS?
